# Why do I get a context must be a dict rather than type

Tags: python, django, http

I've been working on a project for a while, and I have a resource called Item.

The item detail view can only be viewed, if the item is from the same company as the user. If not, it should be a 404. This is the code that I have:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # To only show items in your company
    if (context['item'].company != getCompany(self.request.user)):
        return HttpResponseNotFound

    return context
```

`getCompany` is a function I wrote to check the users company. The company is in a custom `Profile` model. This function works, I already used it multiple times for other things

Now i expected to have a 404 when going to a item from another company, but instead this error appears:

```
    Internal Server Error: /fr/items/5/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Work/Inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Work/Inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Work/Inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Work/Inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Work/Inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 58, in render
    context = make_context(
  File "/Users/username/Documents/Work/Inventory/inventory-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/context.py", line 278, in make_context
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than type.
```

**Edited:**

What did I miss?

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`get_context_data(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method supposed to be return a `dict` object. In your case, you are returning a `HttpResponseNotFound` which is not correct.

The easy method to raise the `404` error is to use the [**`Http404`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404) class to raise the exception

```py
from django.http import Http404


def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    # To only show items in your company
    if (context['item'].company != getCompany(self.request.user)):
        raise Http404

    return context
```

Answer (score 1):

as **Django doc**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
```

is used to

> Returns a dictionary representing the template context. The keyword
> arguments provided will make up the returned context

and you are trying to return **HttpResponseNotFound**, that will not work, you should return dict type

Answer (score 1):

Rather raise a `PermissionDenied` error, then return a `Response` incorrectly as the context, it gives better meaning, then Django will return the usual 403 page.

```py
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # To only show items in your company
    if (context['item'].company != getCompany(self.request.user)):
        raise PermissionDenied("You are not authorized to view the requested company")
    return context
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works now. I just wanted to make a normal 404 so the user doesn't even know if an item with this id exists. But it works aswell like this